# How to populate data in one array of schema from other array of schema in mongodb

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

```
const dummy1Schema = new mongoose.Schema({
    testArr: [{
        name: {
            type: String
        },
        description: {
            type: String
        }
    }]
})
```

```
const dummy2Schema = new mongoose.Schema({
    testArr2: [{
        name2: {
            type: ObjectId,
            ref: "dummy1Schema"
        }
    }]
})
```

I have two collections similar to these. Now, i want to access testArr data in testArr2.

I am using following to populate

```
dummy2Schema
    .find()
    .populate({
        path: 'testArr2.name2',
        model: 'dummy1Schema',
        populate: {
            path: 'testArr',
            model: 'dummy1Schema'
        }
    })
    .exec(function(err, data) {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log(data);
    });
```

The name2 is giving null value

Answer (score 0):

you can populate it in your controller like this

Dummy2Schema.find({}).populate({path:'testArr2.name2'})

Comment: This won't work i tried already